# How to scan HBASE table based only on column value and irrespective of column family?

Tags: hbase

I have a HBASE table with 4 different column families and each column family has 4 resembling columns. I want to perform a search operation on specific column irrespective of its column family. I tried singleColumnValueFilter but it requires a column family. When I tried with ValueFilter, I am getting only the matching columns in result set, not the entire row. Kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FilterList](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FilterList.html) to combine four SingleColumnValueFilter instances.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution which is more general and don't mind using custom filter, [here](https://github.com/sel-fish/hbase-experiments/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mogujie/mst/hbase/filters/CustomFilterForKalisamy.java) is an example which you can use.

This filter extends `ValueFilter` and override `filterRowCells` method.